# Система вопрос ответ на php

Tags: php

У меня есть база данных с вопросами где есть три колонки. Id , answer , question. ID auto_increment индекс primary. В коде я делаю запрос на вопросы и ответы. Мне нужно, как-то привязать первый ответ именно к первому вопросу. Чтобы если был выведен первый вопрос на него был только один ответ. Всего в базе 6 строк, но их будет больше. Вот код.

```
<?php
// Подключение у БД
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("school48") or die(mysql_error());

// Запросы на вопросы и ответы

$questionAnswer1 = mysql_query('SELECT answer, question FROM `answer_from_user` WHERE id="0"');
$questionAnswerRow1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionAnswer1);
$questionAnswer2 = mysql_query('SELECT answer, question FROM `answer_from_user` WHERE id="1"');
$questionAnswerRow2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionAnswer2);
$questionAnswer3 = mysql_query('SELECT answer, question FROM `answer_from_user` WHERE id="2"');
$questionAnswerRow3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionAnswer3);
$questionAnswer4 = mysql_query('SELECT answer, question FROM `answer_from_user` WHERE id="3"');
$questionAnswerRow4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionAnswer4);
$questionAnswer5 = mysql_query('SELECT answer, question FROM `answer_from_user` WHERE id="4"');
$questionAnswerRow5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionAnswer5);
$questionAnswer6 = mysql_query('SELECT answer, question FROM `answer_from_user` WHERE id="5"');
$questionAnswerRow6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionAnswer6);

// Упрощение переменных

// Создание массива с вопросами

$questions = array();
$questions[] = $questionAnswerRow1['question'];
$questions[] = $questionAnswerRow2['question'];
$questions[] = $questionAnswerRow3['question'];
$questions[] = $questionAnswerRow4['question'];
$questions[] = $questionAnswerRow5['question'];
$questions[] = $questionAnswerRow6['question'];


// Создание массива с ответами 

$answers = array();
$answers[] = $questionAnswerRow1['answer'];
$answers[] = $questionAnswerRow2['answer'];
$answers[] = $questionAnswerRow3['answer'];
$answers[] = $questionAnswerRow4['answer'];
$answers[] = $questionAnswerRow5['answer'];
$answers[] = $questionAnswerRow6['answer'];



// Получение доступа к полю ввода ответа

$label = $_REQUEST['label'];
$label = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["label"]);

// Проверка запроса

if (!$questionAnswer1 || !$questionAnswer2 || !$questionAnswer3 || !$questionAnswer4 || !$questionAnswer5 || !$questionAnswer6) {
      echo 'Ошибка запроса: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

// Сравнение ответа

if (!empty($_REQUEST['label'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['label'] == $answers['0']) {
        echo 'Answer Right' . '<br>';

 } else echo 'Answer False' . '<br>';
}

// Рандомное генерирование вопросов
$rand_values = mt_rand(0 , count($questions) - 1);

echo $questions[$rand_values];
echo '<br>'; 
echo '<input type="text" placeholder="Введите ответ например 1992г" name="label"/>';
echo '<button>'.Отправить.'</button>';
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте к каждый строке с вопросами в базе данных, новое поле `response_id`, далее соотвественно создайте в базе данных таблицу для ответов, и после получения ответа к вопросу, сохраняйте ответ в той таблице, а потом `ID` ответа сохраняйте в поле `response_id`. Таким образом вы реализуете связь ответов с вопросами.

Comment: Можно поподробнее. Просто я не силен в php. Как сохранять данные в БД?

Comment: Ну вот в вашем коде используется устаревшая(это сейчас не так важно) функция `mysql_query` Для запроса данных, вы можете в этой же функции дальше, писать запросы к СУБД на сохранение данные, используя обычные `SQL` Команды.

Comment: То есть мне нужно сначала выводить форму. Далее проверять если то что ввел пользователь равно ответу в таблице для ответов тогда добавлять responce_id для вопроса?

Comment: Нет, когда человек ответил, вы заносите ответ в таблицу для ответ, а потом каждый новый ответ пророете, есть ли Типа ответ для этого вопроса, есл есть, не сохраняем, если нет, сохраняем.

Comment: А как привзать ответ к вопросу. То есть чтобы для первого вопроса был правильным только один ответ. Просто я вывожу рандомные вопросы. В коде видно, что я создаю массив, а потом вытягиваю из него рандомное значение и оно выводится. И php не понимает когда какой вопрос вывелся. Поэтому мне нужно привязать в phpmyadmin первый ответ к первому вопросу. Как это сделать?

Comment: Получается сейчас вы все ответы засовываете в одну пачку, а хотите чтобы к каждому вопросу был свой ответ?

Comment: Скажите какая ваша задача с нуля, чтобы я самом дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать систему ВОПРОС-ОТВЕТ. То есть у меня есть сайт. Там есть кнопка перейти в интернет и когда пользователь нажимает он переходит на эту сраницу. Там выводятся разные текстовые вопросы, то есть у меня есть массив и я из него постоянно вытягиваю разные вопросы. Мне нужно чтобы если то, что ввел пользователь равно первому ответу, то выводить ссылку на гугл или еще куда-нибудь. Короче если ответ правильный делать редирект в интернет. Поэтому мне нужно привязать именно первый ответ к первому вопросу, чтобы для первого вопроса правильным ответом был только первый ответ.

Comment: В базе данных у меня все распределено по строчкам. То есть в первой строчке есть id question и answer. И во второй строчке тоже id question answer, но мне нужно чтобы ответ из первой строчки был правильным ответом только для вопроса из этой же первой строчки. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score -1):

Можно как-то так поступить
БД со структурой. Одна таблица с 3-ми колонками.

```
|id|question|answer|
```

и код question.php

```
<?php

    $connect_db = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');

    if (!$connect_db) {
        echo 'Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с Базой Данных!<br>Код ошибки: '.mysqli_connect_errno().'<br>Описание ошибки: '.mysqli_connect_error();
        exit;
    }  elseif (!mysqli_set_charset($connect_db, "utf8")) {
        echo "Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8:". mysqli_error($connect_db);
        exit;
    }

    //запрос с бд
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `question`"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connect_db, $query);

    //проверяем что результат не пустой
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        //возвращаем результат запроса в качестве ассоциативного массива
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {      
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    //Выбираем вопрос
    $rand_id = rand(0, count($data)-1);
    $question = $data[$rand_id];

    //проверяем ответ
    if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['answer'] != '') {

        $id = (int)(trim($_POST['id']));
        $answer_user = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['answer']));

        $query = "SELECT `answer` FROM `question` WHERE `id` = $id"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($connect_db, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            //возвращаем результат запроса
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {      
                $data = $row;
            }
        }

        if($answer_user == $data['answer']){
            echo "True";
        } else {
            echo "False";
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form method="POST" >
        <h3>Вопрос: <?= $question['question']?> </h3>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $question['id']?>">
        <!-- Ответ -->
        <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer">
        <input type="submit" value="Ответ">
    </form>
```